# Dynamically change Quill toolbar visibility

Tags: editor, hide, toolbar, show, quill

I know that on instantiation of a Quill editor, there is a toolbar visibility option. Is there a way that I can change this toolbar visibility  dynamically after the editor is instantiated?

```
options = {
            debug: 'info',
            placeholder: "Place your content here",
            readOnly: false,
            theme: 'snow',
            modules: {
                toolbar: toolbarOptions --> i want to change this property as false at runtime
            },
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the option is not just visibility, it's whether to create a toolbar at all or not. A toolbar cannot be added or removed after the editor is initialized. If you just want to control visibility, one option is just to use CSS to show/hide the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use display: none/block too it's working. It will create or delete the element. Show/hide is a bit different i let you find why.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the tooltip hide/show function like this:
`quill.theme.tooltip.hide()` or `quill.theme.tooltip.show()`